# Rails When using dependent destroy and dependent nullify

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know about relation dependent destroy and dependent nullify on rails and relation with SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:
Table users and table cars

user has many cars
car belongs to users

in table car you have user_id on each row

if you set dependent destroy when defining the relationship in users, then when you delete a user, all cars having that user_id will be deleted also

if you set nullify, cars will remain, but the user_id column will be set to null (it is pointless to have any value there because the user with that id was deleted)

Hope that this helps

Comment: thanks you Eduard. On your case what the best suggestion on deleting? using destroy or nullify?

Comment: I use destroy on most of my has_many and nullify in has_and_belongs_to_many. PS don't forget to choose the right answer if it helped you

Comment: how to set a custom value rather than null?

Answer (score 0):

You use these options when you want to get rid of orphaned records. 
Most common used is `destroy` because it removes all associated objects one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependent when we want to get rid of orphaned records since they can lead to various problems. Orphaned records are created when we delete or destroy a model A that was associated with model B, but model B wasn't removed in the process.

You most often want to use destroy - all associated objects will remove one by one.
other common options are:

`:delete_all` – all associated objects will be deleted in a single query.

`:nullify` – foreign keys  will be set to NULL

You can check more details about [this here](https://kolosek.com/rails-associations/).